# Delete a row in XML from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to see if it is possible to delete some data from xml by using stored procedure.

Im having an XML file which every time I add data into my table it will add it into my XML file as well.
Here is an example of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<appSchedule>

<task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="79"/>
<task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="80"/>
<task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="81"/>
</appSchedule>
```

As you can see Name and Time both are field in my table.
which Name is the id for the record in my table and its unique.

I want to know if there is a way, when I delete the `Name=79` form my database to delete that raw from XML file as well?
Here is my storedprocedure for delete. `SmsSCh_ID` value is the same as `Name` in XML

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cp_SmsSchPrj_Delete]
@SmsSCh_ID bigint = null,
@SmsSCh_IDs nvarchar(1000)=null
,@SmsSCh_UserIDReg int = null
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION SmsSCh
if (@SmsSCh_ID is not null)
begin
Delete from Prj_SmsSch where SmsSCh_ID=@SmsSCh_ID
select 1
end
else
begin 
delete from Prj_SmsSch where SmsSCh_ID in (SELECT * FROM UF_CSVToTable(@SmsSCh_IDs))
end  
COMMIT TRANSACTION SmsSCh
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SmsSCh
RETURN ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
END
```

Thank you

Comment: How is this XML generated? The datetime-format looks culture specific, which is very unusual (and dangerous)...

Comment: Are you using a StoredProcedure (such as `DeleteFromAppShedule`) do delete one row from you physical table? And you want to delete this row from your XML file in the same go? Why do you need this at all? It seems much easier to generate the XML from table data when you need it...

Comment: well the xml file is created from the application which i do not have any access to the source code.

Comment: So the data is coming into your database via XML, generated by some kind of application. You store this XML and - additionally - write the values into *normal* table data? Any change to your table data should be reflected in the XML as well... Correct?

Comment: Yes there's a way, Which one depends on your system architecture. Sql server has `modify` method for XML data type for example. This method  supports XML DML operators including `delete`.

Comment: the reason i need this is the is another application read the xml file all the time. yes i want to StoredProcedure (such as DeleteFromAppShedule) to delete one row.

Comment: could you please give me a link so i can read about this method. or if you can give me some guide on how to do this?

Comment: Hi @webeditor, there's something I do not understand: The XML your are talking about is linving in files on your disk? Just one XML or many different files? It is quite easy to read the XML from a file-location, but not so easy to write the modified XML back. You speak about *changing all the time*: How often? Concurrent access possible?

Comment: Dear @Shnugo yes the xml is in my hard disk. when a record add into a specific table same record is added into the xml file as well. how offen it depend to the users how offen add record into that table i cant tell.

Comment: The Xml files must reside in the location? Are they read by other program later? If ever possible you should avoid to keep the same data in two places (and - even worse - in absolutely different structures...) Please use the edit option of your question and add some lines: Explain the process: How get the data into your tables, how are they changing, Where is the one / are the many XML files, How are they recognized, Might the XML change *from outside* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about `XML DML delete` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190254.aspx
Example

```
declare @x XML =
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSchedule>
<task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="79"/>
<task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="80"/>
<task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="81"/>
</appSchedule>'
--- read from file. Path is relative to server machine
SELECT @x = cast(x.bulkColumn as XML) 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\mydir\myfile.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS x

set @x.modify('delete  /appSchedule/task[@name="79"]');

select @x;
```

About `OPENROWSET BULK SINGLE_BLOB` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i read the xml file from c:/appchedule.xml.

Comment: i did run the second part but it did not delete the record from the xml file. as a resault it shows that its deleted but in the file its still exist.

Comment: Yes, it  was deleted from local var @x. Now you need to save it back to file. See this article https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/  , it shows  how to save data to file using Ms Sql OLE automation procedures.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @x XML = N'
<appSchedule>
    <task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="79"/>
    <task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="80"/>
    <task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="81"/>
    <task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="82"/>
</appSchedule>'

DECLARE @ignore_list TABLE (id INT)
INSERT INTO @ignore_list VALUES (79), (82)

DECLARE @t VARCHAR(50) = ''
SELECT @t += ',' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(8000)) FROM @ignore_list
SET @t += ','

SET @x.modify('delete /appSchedule/task[(contains(sql:variable("@t"), concat(",", @name, ",")))]')

SELECT @x
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but XML file values are changing all the time and they are in a file in my c:/appchedule.xml

Comment: Did you know this values before parse xml from file?

Comment: i know the value that has to be deleted

Answer (score 1):

This was my approach

```
CREATE TABLE #yourXmlStore (ID INT, YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO #yourXmlStore VALUES
(1,'<appSchedule>
    <task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="79"/>
    <task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="80"/>
    <task time="08/06/2016 9:25:00" name="81"/>
    </appSchedule>');

CREATE TABLE #yourData (ID INT IDENTITY, name VARCHAR(100),time DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #yourData(name,time) VALUES
 ('79',{ts'2016-06-08 09:25:00'})
,('80',{ts'2016-06-08 09:25:00'})
,('81',{ts'2016-06-08 09:25:00'});
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteTask @name VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM #yourData WHERE name=@name;
    UPDATE #yourXmlStore SET YourXML.modify('delete /appSchedule/task[@name=sql:variable("@name")]');
END
GO

SELECT * FROM #yourData;
SELECT * FROM #yourXmlStore;
EXEC DeleteTask @name='79';
SELECT * FROM #yourData;
SELECT * FROM #yourXmlStore;
GO

DROP TABLE #yourData;
DROP TABLE #yourXmlStore;   
DROP PROCEDURE DeleteTask;
```

Comment: I did run your code and in the result section it working fine but it doesnt save the result into the xml file.

Comment: @webeditor, I do not understand this concept... Is there just one file holding all XML entries, are there many files? Which one is to modify? Why are the files (and the changes) needed somewhere down the file system?